# Allow embed code on django template?

Tags: html, django, iframe, django-templates

I want to show user like this:

**Embed on your website**

```
<iframe src="imgurl"></iframe>
```

I don't want `iframe` tag to render. I want to show raw html in the django template. How can I do that? I tried using `verbatim` tag like this:

```
{% verbatim %}
<iframe src="imgurl"></iframe>
{% endverbatim %}
```

But no, django template is trying to render the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<pre>
  &lt;iframe 
  src=&quot;imgurl&quot;&gt;
  &lt;/iframe&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the Django template has nothing to do with this. Your browser sees an iframe and includes it; Django doesn't control what happens in that iframe, because it's taken from a completely separate URL.

Comment: So how can I control that via html? I don't want to show the text `<iframe src="imgurl"></iframe>` not render it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [character codes](http://character-code.com/) / HTML entities for this. Something like:

```
<pre>
    &lt;iframe src="imgurl"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
</pre>
```